# GhostPDL convert PCL with asian fonts

Tags: fonts, ghostscript, printer-control-language

I need to convert PCL to PDF documents with Asian fonts. I can not find information on this type of PCL fonts. I have no problems with pdf and Ps documents, as I have configured Ghostscript (cifmap and environment variables).
Thanks in advance

Comment: And what precise problem are you encountering ?

Comment: Hi KenS, When converting the PCL document or viewing it with ghostpdl, the asian fonts are not displayed. However, no error message appears.

Answer (score 0):

Does the PCL file contain fonts ?

I'm assuming the file does not contain fonts, as you say the text is missing when you 'view' the file using GhostPDL. I'm guessing you mean render to the display device when you say 'view'.

Unlike PostScript, PCL doesn't really have a mechanism for supplying fonts externally, if the file doesn't contain the fonts then you will get the basic replacement, Courier or whatever, which really isn't going to work well with CJKV fonts. Or any other non-Latin language come to that.

FWIW if the display device doesn't render the PCL as expected, then pdfwrite has no hope of creating a PDF file that does.